# Making use of previous saved model checkpoint for training on new data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I was experimenting with model checkpoints with the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback, TensorBoard, ModelCheckpoint

def get_model():
    # Create a simple model.
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=(32,))
    outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1)(inputs)
    model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
    model.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = "mean_squared_error")
    return model

# Creating the model
model = get_model()

# Checkpoint of model weights
weights_filename = "weights/model_best_weights"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(weights_filename, monitor = 'loss', verbose = 1, save_best_only = True, save_weights_only = True, mode = 'auto', period = 1)


# Train the model.
test_input = np.random.random((128, 32))
test_target = np.random.random((128, 1))
model.fit(test_input, test_target, verbose = 2, callbacks=[checkpoint])

# Calling `save('my_model')` creates a SavedModel folder `my_model`.
model.save("my_model")
```

After training the model,

```
WARNING:tensorflow:`period` argument is deprecated. Please use `save_freq` to specify the frequency in number of batches seen.
4/4 - 0s - loss: 4.5422

Epoch 00001: loss improved from inf to 4.54224, saving model to weights/model_best_weights
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: my_model/assets
```

```
# It can be used to reconstruct the model identically.
reconstructed_model = keras.models.load_model("my_model")
weights_filename = "weights/model_best_weights"
reconstructed_model.load_weights(weights_filename)  # Loading previous saved weights

#This is creating the problem -->  Problem of creating new checkpoint
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(weights_filename, monitor = 'loss', verbose = 1, save_best_only = True, save_weights_only = True, mode = 'auto', period = 1)
```

Using the reloaded model for training another data:

```
# The reconstructed model is already compiled and has retained the optimizer
# state, so training can resume:
test_input = np.random.random((128, 32))
test_target = np.random.random((128, 1))

reconstructed_model.fit(test_input, test_target, verbose = 2, callbacks = [checkpoint])
```

The loss comes as

```
4/4 - 0s - loss: 3.8699
 
Epoch 00001: loss improved from inf to 3.86991, saving model to
weights/model_best_weights
```

The issue here is that I am instantiating a `ModelCheckpoint` again in order to save the best weight checkpoints.

Shouldn't the training loss start from the last saved best checkpoint that was created earlier?

Comment: Are you wondering why it starts with `inf`?

Comment: Yes. actually, this is what my question is more focused on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the thing is when you create an instance from the `ModelCheckpoint(Callback)` class, it sets the monitoring parameter to `inf (-/+)`. That's why when you second time creates the instance of this class, it sets such init value for the monitoring parameter. You can see the source code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/85c8b2a817f95a3e979ecd1ed95bff1dc1335cff/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py#L1287) and that further lead [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/85c8b2a817f95a3e979ecd1ed95bff1dc1335cff/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py#L1388) logs.

```
...
    if mode == 'min':
      self.monitor_op = np.less
      self.best = np.Inf
    elif mode == 'max':
      self.monitor_op = np.greater
      self.best = -np.Inf
    else:
      if 'acc' in self.monitor or self.monitor.startswith('fmeasure'):
        self.monitor_op = np.greater
        self.best = -np.Inf
      else:
        self.monitor_op = np.less
        self.best = np.Inf
...
```